# Guarantee asyncio execution order

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have seen other answers on here stating that asyncio doesn't guarantee execution order, only that the order of the outputs will match that of the inputs.

Is there a way I *can* guarantee the execution order

For example, if I have a list of the functions I want to run, will calling create task on each of them before calling gather work? Is there something else I can do to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with `asyncio.Event`:

```
async def perform_task(listen_event, push_event):
    await do_some_paralell_work()
    await listen_event.wait()
    await do_some_work_in_order()
    if push_event:
        await push-event.set()

async def main():
    events = [asyncio.Event() for i in range(100)]
    tasks = [asyncio.Task(events[i], events[i+1] if i<100 else None) for i in range(100)]
    events[0].set()
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

This should let the parallel work run in parallel but then run the final statement in order

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to read the section on [asyncio syncrhonization](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html). You have have one task wait on an `Event` that is set by another task.

Comment: Ah, so I can use an event to notify the next task when it is ready to be executed. I'll have a look at this - thank you!

Comment: yes, this can be done, but creatign a co-routine with `await` expressions for the tasks yu need to execute in order is a lot simpler and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `asyncio.ensure_future()` instead of `asyncio.create_task()` to create the tasks. This makes sure that tasks are scheduled in the order they were created. Once they are scheduled in order we can use `await asyncio.gather(*task_list)`
to execute tasks in the order they are created.

> However ensure_future() does not guarantee the exact execution order if tasks have different durations. It ensures the order they are scheduled but execution still depends on various other factors.

The best way should be to use `await`  keyword to await the completion of each task before moving on to the next one. This will guarantee execution order but they will be executed sequentially.

If you require more fine-grained control, you can(use locks) lock a critical section so that only one task can execute the critical section at a time.

Comment: If the argument to `ensure_future` is a coroutine, then `ensure_future` will call `create_task`.  In that case there is no difference between the two functions, except that `ensure_future` adds a little bit of overhead.  This is the case in 3.11 and probably for a few earlier versions.  See the library source code in tasks.py.